# Grep: using with -e and -o options together

Tags: linux, bash, grep, solaris

Need to parse big log file in one run and print *id*, *address* and *service_name* of found requests. The problem is that *service_name* is in request body that is quite big.

If I list all patterns with `-e` option -

`grep -e 'ID: [0-9]\+' -e 'Address: .*' -e ':Body><[^ ]*'`

the full request body will be printed.

What is needed is

`grep -e 'ID: [0-9]\+' -e 'Address: .*' -o ':Body><[^ ]*'`

or

`grep -o 'ID: [0-9]\+' -o 'Address: .*' -o ':Body><[^ ]*'`

to print only first word from request body that is name of the service;

but in this case `grep: :Body><[^ ]*: No such file or directory` error received

UPD: solution with `-oe` and regex works, but as it turned out `-o` significantly slows the operation

Comment: try `-oe` ( not tested)

Comment: same error with `-oe`

Comment: Is it [tag:linux] or [tag:solaris]? They're not the same.

Comment: I don't have access to a solaris system, but on both Mac and Linux when I use `-eo` I get "No such file", but if I use '-oe` as @P.... suggested, it works.

Comment: Are the log entries all a single line?

Comment: it is solaris with ggrep. log entries are in separate lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to print only bits of a file that match these 3 regular expressions and those three are never on the same line, you may use `\|`, which is grep's logical or :

```
grep -o 'ID: [0-9]\+\|Address: .*\|:Body><[^ ]*' my.log
```

Comment: it is ok but works _x number_of_patterns_ times slower

Comment: Have you tried tuning (LC_ALL='C') to improve grep performance? This command is slower than if you had only one pattern for sure, but is it slower than any other "one run" solution?

Comment: even with changed locale result is the same. Yes, with regex it is n times slower than if with expressions listed with `-e` option

Comment: If you're looking for optimization, this trick should boost performance up: you could prepend with "ID:" & "Address:" with "^" if you're sure those two words are at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your log its difficult to fully understand what your example will return. You might try -Eo and see if that helps get what you want. You may need to adjust the regex accordingly. -E should at least resolve your "grep: :Body><[^ ]*: No such file or directory" error you're receiving.

```
grep -Eo 'ID: [0-9]\+' -Eo 'Address: .*' -Eo ':Body><[^ ]*' myLog.log
```

Comment: on Solaris ggrep gives the same error `grep: :Body><[^ ]*: No such file or directory`

Comment: This answer may be sensitive to the version of grep you're using. I'm using grep (GNU grep) 2.27